# Will anything bad happen if I push two app contexts during testing?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pytest, fixtures

I'm using Flask, Mongo (with Flask-PyMongo), and py.test. I have a py.test fixture for my app which is as you'd expect:

```
@pytest.fixture
def app(request):
    from proj import app

    ctx = app.app_context()
    ctx.push()
    request.addfinalizer(lambda: ctx.pop())

    return app
```

I also have a Mongo fixture. Now, the `mongo` object is created with Flask-PyMongo and so it requires an app context to work. I have come up with the following:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mongo():
    from proj import app, mongo

    ctx = app.app_context()
    ctx.push()
    request.addfinalizer(lambda: ctx.pop())

    return mongo
```

This works in that if I have a test like this it works:

```
def test_mongo(mongo):
    assert mongo.db.coll.find({'foo': 'bar'}).count() > 0
```

However, in some cases I want access both to the app and to the database:

```
def test_app_and_mongo(app, mongo):
    assert serious_stuff(app, mongo)
```

This will cause two app contexts to be created. As it is now it just works, but given I don't understand Flask very well yet, I am wary.

Will this cause anything bad to happen? Is there any surprising behavior I will see because of this?

---

For reference, `proj`'s `__init__.py` is something like:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)
# ... set config ... 
mongo = PyMongo(app)
```

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't affect anything, but it's not necessary. Make the `mongo` fixture depend on the `app` fixture, which already sets up the context.

```
import pytest
from proj import app as flask_app, mongo as mongo_ext

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    with flask_app.app_context():
        yield flask_app

@pytest.fixture
def mongo(app):
    return mongo_ext

def test_with_app(app):
    ...

def test_with_mongo(mongo):
    ...

def test_with_both(app, mongo):
    ...
```

---

Since the `mongo` fixture isn't doing anything else, you can remove it.  Import the extension object directly and make your test depend on the `app` fixture to set up the context. (Although I assume in the real fixture you're doing some database setup/cleanup.)